# Vaadin 6 . Set table heigth to fit context

Tags: java, vaadin6

I have a `Table` in my project inside a `Panel` inside a `VerticalLayout` and I need to set table height to fit the context. If I set

```
table.setsizeFull() ;
table.setPageLength(0);
```

then table height is much smaller than necessary and there are vertical scrollbar.

I tried to do like this:

```
table.setPageLength(table.getItemIds().size() + 1);
table.requestRepaint();
```

but in this case there are a lot of space under the table. I tried to set `setSizeFull()` for all elements but this has no effect.
When I tried this:

```
table.setPageLength(table.getItemIds().size());
table.requestRepaint();
```

effect was the same, as in first case (smaller height and vertical scrollbar).
How can I set table heigth to fit context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by this:

```
table.setWidth(100, UNITS_PERCENTAGE); 
table.setHeight(SIZE_UNDEFINED, 0);
table.setPageLength(0);
```